# Is it possible to sign a transaction using eth_sign?

Tags: web3js, transactions, signature

I am trying to sign a transaction, but not submit it. That would be possible using eth_signTransaction, but Metamask doesn't support it yet. I heard that it would be possible to sign a transaction using eth_sign, does anyone know how this can be done?

Thanks!